# Сохранение талицы бд и синхронизация

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Как Сохранить таблицу из БД SQL-Server на компе и какие способы существуют. А затем при необходимости синхронизировать эти таблицы (таблицы на сервере и на компе)?

Comment: Кроме XML документа какие еще есть способы.

Comment: Если XML наиболее эффективный, то тогда как сравнивать datatable? Построчно или каждую ячейку.

Comment: [LiteDB](http://www.litedb.org/), [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)

Comment: Про существование SQLite знаю, но как в нее сохранить

Comment: Таблица в MS SQL-server <-> Класс C# <-> Таблица в SQLite

Comment: Сразу появляется много вопросов. Какой объем данных в таблице, каков промежуток времени между синхронизациями, как часто другие клиенты вносят изменения на сервере, можете ли вы модифицировать структуру базы на сервере? В общем случае вы сталкиваетесь с двухсторонней гетерогенной синхронизацией, что, прямо скажем, не тривиальная задача. Но если данных мало, меняются они редко, и вы можете внести изменения на сервере, то в этом частном случае она решается довольно просто.

Comment: Рациональным ли будет такое решение: При любом изменении бд sqlite записывать индексы изменненых ячеек, и когда понадобиться синхронизация брать этот текстовик и сравнивать только эти поля?

Comment: Вполне. Но лучше не в текстовик, а в табличку в той же базе. У многих серверов встроенная репликация работает именно так.